# 502 Bad Gateway when using Let's Encrypt with Nginx and Node.js on new domain

Tags: node.js, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have recently set up a new domain on my server, following the steps taken as the previous two (which are working fine on HTTPS). When trying to connect to my new site, however, I receive the following `error.log`:

```
2018/10/02 00:54:33 [error] 8536#8536: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 88.98.209.129, server: rees.app, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://139.59.178.110:3500/", host: "rees.app"
```

When running `debug` on this error, I receive:

```
2018/10/02 00:57:14 [debug] 8687#8687: epoll add event: fd:6 op:1 ev:00002001
2018/10/02 00:57:14 [debug] 8687#8687: epoll add event: fd:7 op:1 ev:00002001
2018/10/02 00:57:14 [debug] 8687#8687: epoll add event: fd:8 op:1 ev:00002001
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: accept on 0.0.0.0:443, ready: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: posix_memalign: 000055C3AF691260:512 @16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 accept: 88.98.209.129:48510 fd:3
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 event timer add: 3: 60000:1538441896702
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 reusable connection: 1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 epoll add event: fd:3 op:1 ev:80002001
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http check ssl handshake
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http recv(): 1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 https ssl handshake: 0x16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL ALPN supported by client: h2
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL ALPN supported by client: http/1.1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL ALPN selected: h2
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL server name: "rees.app"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_get_error: 2
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 reusable connection: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL handshake handler: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL: TLSv1.2, cipher: "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH Au=RSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 init http2 connection
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 posix_memalign: 000055C3AF69F6F0:512 @16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 posix_memalign: 000055C3AF63FFA0:4096 @16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 add cleanup: 000055C3AF6913E0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 posix_memalign: 000055C3AF69F900:512 @16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 send SETTINGS frame ack:0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 send WINDOW_UPDATE frame sid:0, window:2147418112
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 read handler
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_read: -1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_get_error: 2
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame out: 000055C3AF6400A8 sid:0 bl:0 len:4
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame out: 000055C3AF63FFF0 sid:0 bl:0 len:18
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 malloc: 000055C3AF632C00:16384
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL buf copy: 27
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL buf copy: 13
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL to write: 40
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_write: 40
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 tcp_nodelay
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame sent: 000055C3AF63FFF0 sid:0 bl:0 len:18
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame sent: 000055C3AF6400A8 sid:0 bl:0 len:4
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free: 000055C3AF63FFA0, unused: 3656
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free: 000055C3AF632C00
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 reusable connection: 1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 event timer del: 3: 1538441896702
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 event timer add: 3: 180000:1538442016709
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 idle handler
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 reusable connection: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 posix_memalign: 000055C3AF63FFA0:4096 @16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 read handler
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_read: 64
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_read: -1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_get_error: 2
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 preface verified
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 process http2 frame type:4 f:0 l:18 sid:0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 send SETTINGS frame ack:1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame complete pos:000055C3AF6FC5C3 end:000055C3AF6FC5D0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 process http2 frame type:8 f:0 l:4 sid:0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 WINDOW_UPDATE frame sid:0 window:15663105
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame complete pos:000055C3AF6FC5D0 end:000055C3AF6FC5D0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame out: 000055C3AF63FFF0 sid:0 bl:0 len:0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 malloc: 000055C3AF632C00:16384
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL buf copy: 9
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL to write: 9
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_write: 9
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame sent: 000055C3AF63FFF0 sid:0 bl:0 len:0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free: 000055C3AF63FFA0, unused: 3855
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free: 000055C3AF632C00
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 reusable connection: 1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 event timer: 3, old: 1538442016709, new: 1538442016709
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 idle handler
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 reusable connection: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 posix_memalign: 000055C3AF63FFA0:4096 @16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 read handler
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_read: 284
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_read: -1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_get_error: 2
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 process http2 frame type:1 f:25 l:275 sid:1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 HEADERS frame sid:1 on 0 excl:1 weight:256
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 posix_memalign: 000055C3AF69FB10:1024 @16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 posix_memalign: 000055C3AF6A0800:4096 @16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 posix_memalign: 000055C3AF6A1810:4096 @16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 get indexed header name: 2
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 get indexed header: 1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack encoded string length: 6
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 add header to hpack table: ":authority: rees.app"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 malloc: 000055C3AF69FF20:512
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 malloc: 000055C3AF632C00:4096
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack table account: 50 free:4096
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 get indexed header name: 7
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 get indexed header name: 4
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http uri: "/"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http args: ""
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http exten: ""
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 get indexed header: 24
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack encoded string length: 7
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 add header to hpack table: "cache-control: max-age=0"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack table account: 54 free:4046
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 http header: "cache-control: max-age=0"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack encoded string length: 18
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack raw string length: 1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 add header to hpack table: "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack table account: 58 free:3992
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 http header: "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 get indexed header: 58
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack encoded string length: 92
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 add header to hpack table: "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack table account: 163 free:3934
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 http header: "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 get indexed header: 19
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack encoded string length: 64
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 add header to hpack table: "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack table account: 123 free:3771
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 http header: "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 get indexed header: 16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack encoded string length: 13
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 add header to hpack table: "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack table account: 64 free:3648
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 posix_memalign: 000055C3AF6A0130:512 @16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 http header: "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 get indexed header: 17
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack encoded string length: 11
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 add header to hpack table: "accept-language: en,en-GB;q=0.9"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack table account: 61 free:3584
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 http header: "accept-language: en,en-GB;q=0.9"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 get indexed header: 32
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack encoded string length: 38
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 add header to hpack table: "cookie: __cfduid=dcb5ea66f953195d1aeec15d5d437be411538438395"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 hpack table account: 90 free:3523
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 http request line: "GET / HTTP/2.0"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 generic phase: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 rewrite phase: 1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 test location: "/"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 using configuration "/"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 generic phase: 5
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 generic phase: 6
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 generic phase: 7
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 access phase: 8
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 access phase: 9
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 access phase: 10
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 post access phase: 11
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http body new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 0000000000000000, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http init upstream, client timer: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "Cookie: "
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script var: "__cfduid=dcb5ea66f953195d1aeec15d5d437be411538438395"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "
"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "Host: "
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script var: "rees.app"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "
"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: ""
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: ""
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-For: "
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script var: "88.98.209.129"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "
"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-Host: "
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script var: "rees.app"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "
"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-Server: "
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script var: "rees.app"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "
"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "X-Real-IP: "
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script var: "88.98.209.129"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "
"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "X-Forwarded-Proto: "
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script var: "https"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "
"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "X-Original-Request: "
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script var: "/"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "
"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: "Connection: close
"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: ""
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: ""
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: ""
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http script copy: ""
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http proxy header: "cache-control: max-age=0"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http proxy header: "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http proxy header: "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http proxy header: "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http proxy header: "accept-language: en,en-GB;q=0.9"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http proxy header:
"GET / HTTP/1.1
Cookie: __cfduid=dcb5ea66f953195d1aeec15d5d437be411538438395
Host: rees.app
X-Forwarded-For: 88.98.209.129
X-Forwarded-Host: rees.app
X-Forwarded-Server: rees.app
X-Real-IP: 88.98.209.129
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Original-Request: /
Connection: close
cache-control: max-age=0
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-language: en,en-GB;q=0.9

"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 posix_memalign: 000055C3AF633C10:4096 @16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http cleanup add: 000055C3AF6A27E8
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 get rr peer, try: 1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 stream socket 12
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 epoll add connection: fd:12 ev:80002005
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 connect to 139.59.178.110:3500, fd:12 #2
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http upstream connect: -2
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 posix_memalign: 000055C3AF687DF0:128 @16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 event timer add: 12: 59000:1538441895710
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http finalize request: -4, "/?" a:1, c:2
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http request count:2 blk:0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame complete pos:000055C3AF6FC6AC end:000055C3AF6FC6AC
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 event timer del: 3: 1538442016709
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http upstream request: "/?"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http upstream send request handler
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 malloc: 000055C3AF69ACC0:72
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 upstream SSL server name: "rees.app"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 set session: 0000000000000000
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 tcp_nodelay
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_do_handshake: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_get_error: 5
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [error] 8687#8687: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 88.98.209.129, server: rees.app, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://139.59.178.110:3500/", host: "rees.app"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http next upstream, 2
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free rr peer 1 4
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 finalize http upstream request: 502
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 finalize http proxy request
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 close http upstream connection: 12
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free: 000055C3AF69ACC0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free: 000055C3AF687DF0, unused: 32
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 event timer del: 12: 1538441895710
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 reusable connection: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http finalize request: 502, "/?" a:1, c:1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http special response: 502, "/?"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 xslt filter header
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 header filter
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 output header: ":status: 502"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 output header: "server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 output header: "date: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 00:57:16 GMT"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 output header: "content-type: text/html"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 output header: "content-length: 584"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2:1 create HEADERS frame 000055C3AF633D50: len:62
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http cleanup add: 000055C3AF633E58
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame out: 000055C3AF633D50 sid:1 bl:1 len:62
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 malloc: 000055C3AF695BD0:16384
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL buf copy: 9
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL buf copy: 62
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2:1 HEADERS frame 000055C3AF633D50 was sent
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame sent: 000055C3AF633D50 sid:1 bl:1 len:62
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http output filter "/?"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http copy filter: "/?"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 image filter
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 xslt filter body
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http postpone filter "/?" 000055C3AF633FD8
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000055C3AE362AC0, size: 120 file: 0, size: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000055C3AE363E40, size: 62 file: 0, size: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000055C3AE363C60, size: 402 file: 0, size: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:584
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http write filter limit 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2:1 create DATA frame 000055C3AF633D50: len:584 flags:1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame out: 000055C3AF633D50 sid:1 bl:0 len:584
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL buf copy: 9
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL buf copy: 120
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL buf copy: 62
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL buf copy: 402
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL to write: 664
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_write: 664
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2:1 DATA frame 000055C3AF633D50 was sent
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame sent: 000055C3AF633D50 sid:1 bl:0 len:584
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http write filter 0000000000000000
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/?"
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http finalize request: 0, "/?" a:1, c:1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http request count:1 blk:0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 close stream 1, queued 0, processing 1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http close request
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http log handler
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free: 000055C3AF6A0800, unused: 8
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free: 000055C3AF6A1810, unused: 7
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free: 000055C3AF633C10, unused: 2750
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free: 000055C3AF69FB10, unused: 540
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 post event 000055C3AF6D86F0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 delete posted event 000055C3AF6D86F0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 handle connection handler
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free: 000055C3AF63FFA0, unused: 3488
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free: 000055C3AF695BD0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 reusable connection: 1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 event timer add: 3: 180000:1538442016711
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 idle handler
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 reusable connection: 0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 posix_memalign: 000055C3AF63FFA0:4096 @16
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 read handler
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_read: 9
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_read: -1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 SSL_get_error: 2
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 process http2 frame type:4 f:1 l:0 sid:0
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 http2 frame complete pos:000055C3AF6FC599 end:000055C3AF6FC599
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 free: 000055C3AF63FFA0, unused: 4016
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 reusable connection: 1
2018/10/02 00:57:16 [debug] 8687#8687: *1 event timer: 3, old: 1538442016711, new: 1538442016713
```

I am not very familiar with Nginx or any sysadmin, so this log does not make much sense to me. I have tried deleting and re-creating the certificate files for the website, though this also has not worked. There are two other websites on the host which work perfectly fine, so I'm just unsure as to what is going on here.

This is the server block file:

```
# Remove WWW from HTTP
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.rees.app rees.app;
    return 301 https://rees.app$request_uri;
}

# Remove WWW from HTTPS
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/rees.app/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/rees.app/privkey.pem;
    server_name www.rees.app;
    return 301 https://rees.app$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS request
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name rees.app;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/rees.app/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/rees.app/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3500;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

And this is the `/etc/nginx/proxy_params` file:

```
proxy_buffers 16 32k;
proxy_buffer_size 64k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization;
proxy_connect_timeout 59s;
proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
proxy_no_cache $http_pragma $http_authorization;
proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding '';
proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header Proxy '';
proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Original-Request $request_uri;
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
```

The domain is also set up to use CloudFlare (as with the others), though CloudFlare is 'paused' meaning that it is only used for DNS routing to the server. The server block is also symlinked to `sites-active` and, contrary to the error shown, the site does actually have a valid HTTPS certificate if you visit it. I am unsure what could be causing the 502.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this issue by re-issuing the certificates again. Whilst I had tried this the first time, I did not realise that it is important to remove (to my knowledge the only) three folders from the directories `/accounts`, `/live`, and `/renewal`. I had not done this which is why my renewals did not work.

The best way to ensure that your certificate is correct is to make sure that `/live` contains the certificate, and that `/renewal` contains a `.conf` that is not empty. If any of these are the case then it is likely that the certificate did not deploy correctly and you should take a look to see if you have missed anything.